# why is it, that On file upload, the Application_BeginRequest is not being triggered on published site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I think part of the question is of course, how do I fix this:

I have an ASP.NET MVC site which on the web development environment Cassini triggers the:

> protected void
>   Application_BeginRequest(object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>                    }

on a file upload, but when I publish this to my IIS7 machine it will not trigger this any more..

> It still gets called on any other
>   normal page load, just uploads it
>   isn't

Isapi seems to be what I need to get my hands on, because the request is probably not being handled by MVC on the published site, what can I do to make it so?

Would be nice if I could just tweak my RegisterRouters instead of changing the IIS configuration, but any hint in the right direction is appreciated!

Thank you,

Ric

Comment: Did you checked that form type is "multipart/form-data" for the file upload?

Comment: yeah, it is, it works in Cassini, just not on an IIS7 site